# How to make it better? "Maybe Bool" doesn't look great

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

First of all, I'm a novice in Haskell, so if I'm asking somewhat silly question please tell me how can I do better. Thanks :)

My task is to get a list of strings, conforming to specific condition. If no strings conform, I'd like to evaluate to `Nothing`. So I write two functions:

```hs
isSpecialLine :: String -> String -> Maybe Bool
isSpecialLine t s = Just $ (("[" ++ t ++ ":") `isPrefixOf` s) && ("]::" `isSuffixOf` s)

getLinesWith :: String -> String -> Maybe [String]
getLinesWith t = filterM (isSpecialLine t) . lines
```

This code works, but I find that `Maybe Bool` looks a bit weird. Hey, it's binary! It's always `True` or `False`, so value of `isSpecialLine` will always be `Just True` or `Just False`. It can never be `Nothing` in my case!

But if I change `isSpecialLine` output type to `Bool`, following problem appears: `filterM` expects `Maybe Bool` instead of `Bool`.

Ok, so I do that:

```hs
getLinesWith :: String -> String -> Maybe [String]
getLinesWith t = filterM (Just $ isSpecialLine t) . lines
```

Now compiler complains about unmatching type: `Maybe (String -> Bool)` doesn't match expected `String -> Maybe Bool`. Ok, pretty reasonable. So I:

```hs
getLinesWith :: String -> String -> Maybe [String]
getLinesWith t = Just $ filter (isSpecialLine t) . lines
```

And again type mismatching, this time `Maybe (String -> [String])` is not `String -> Maybe [String]`. What's the correct syntax to wrap `[String]` to `Maybe` monad?

Comment: I think you do not need a `Maybe` here in the first place. A `Maybe` is usually used for non-total functions (so some input that is non-sensical for example).

Answer (score 6):

`isSpecialLine` never produces `Nothing`, so that’s a good hint that `Maybe` might not make sense for it either.

```
isSpecialLine :: String -> String -> Bool
isSpecialLine t s = (("[" ++ t ++ ":") `isPrefixOf` s) && ("]::" `isSuffixOf` s)

getLinesWith :: String -> String -> [String]
getLinesWith t = filter (isSpecialLine t) . lines
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that you do not need a `filterM` here. You can make use of [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) instead:

```
isSpecialLine :: String -> String -> Bool
isSpecialLine t s = isPrefixOf ("[" ++ t ++ ":") s && isSuffixOf "]::" s

getLinesWith :: String -> String -> [String]
getLinesWith t = filter (isSpecialLine t) . lines
```

Indeed, this will return a list of `String`s, where each string that matches the `isSpecialLine` filter will be retained.

Comment: Sure, and it was a first version of `getLinesWith`. But I want to get `Maybe [String]`, not `[String]`. What to do in that case?

Comment: @Pnatone887: under what conditions would `getLinesWith` return `Nothing`?

Comment: It should return `Nothing` if there is no lines that conform to the condition.

Comment: @Pantone877 What difference do you see between `Nothing` and `Just []`?

Comment: @chepner eh, that's a question. Thanks!

I rewrote the function which get the result of `getLinesWith` and now it all looks much better.

Comment: @Pantone877: usually `Maybe` can be seen as a `1+` on type level: we construct *one* extra value. But usually it only makes sense to do that, well, if we need an extra value, to represent something that can not be represented with the *n* other values. I remember a talk by *Tom Schrijvers* about this, but somehow I'm not able to find this immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Willem-Van-Onsem. Please take a look at the solution I've provided; I wish I'd written it before.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Maybe` and unwrap data from `getLinesWith` like this,

```hs
getLinesWith :: String -> String -> Maybe [String]
...

getDate :: String -> String -> UTCTime
getDate t s =
    timeFromString
    . filter (/= ' ')
    . getBetweenColons
    . maybe ":01-01-1971:" head $ getLinesWith t s
```

I finished with much better looking (I hope so) solution without `Maybe`:

```hs
getLinesWith :: String -> String -> [String]
...

getDate :: String -> String -> UTCTime
getDate t s
  | null date = timeFromString "01-01-1971"
  | otherwise = timeFromString
              . filter (/= ' ')
              . getBetweenColons
              . head $ date
  where date = getLinesWith t s
```

Actually, all the dancing around `Maybe` began when GHC complained about `head []`.
Thank you all for input!

Comment: If you use `date = getLinesWith t s ++ ["01-01-1971"]` (or whatever string would be processed down to `"01-01-1971"`), you can guarantee that `date` is a non-empty list, and `head` becomes safe to use.

Comment: Bravo, @chepner! That's even more elegant. I appreciate it very much!